# draw.io plugins in chrome app

Tags: offlineapps, draw.io

In an online version of [draw.io](https://www.draw.io) you can enable extra plugins using their url like this `https://www.draw.io/?p=svgdata` (`svgdata` is the plugin id)

Is there a way to enable a plugin using [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drawio-desktop/pebppomjfocnoigkeepgbmcifnnlndla?hl=en-GB)?

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: not sure how to elaborate... There are plugins in the online version and I can't find how to enable them inside offline version. I need SVG Data plugin when I export my diagrams as SVG to preserve custom data

Comment: The option _Plugins_ is disabled in offline version. Wait. Let me check the chrome app

Comment: It's not technically possible to enable plugins in the Chrome App, it's a limitation of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In online version, the `Plugins` is listed under extras.
[image]

In offline as well as in Chrome App, you can't see such an Option

[image]

Which means you can't add plugins in the offline version.

Remaining functionalities that you will miss in the offline version

---

- You can’t access or store diagrams using cloud services like Dropbox, GitHub, etc.
- Save diagrams to your device or browser instead.
- Online help is not available
- You can’t insert PlantUML text data.
- Math typesetting is not available.
- Templates are not available for creating new diagrams.
- You can’t export to PDF, but you can print as PDF.
- The interface is only available in English.

[source : draw.io](https://support.draw.io/display/DO/Using+draw.io+in+Offline+Mode)

---

#### Then why?

May be because of issues with caching. If you add many plugins, each of them contains many files. Caching large number of files for offline usage will make the app worst and also consume more memory.

Anyway, you can submit a feature request [here](https://draw.uservoice.com/forums/266072-feature-requests)

Comment: Thank you for the investigation. I will try to create feature request.

Comment: anytym. After you submit, update the question with the link so that future visitors can vote your feature request in the site.